# How to configure the path to test.ts in Angular CLI managed project

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, karma-runner

I've used swagger code gen with typescript-angular to generate an API client from a swagger v3 file.  This is really nice, fast, and easy; however, I think the output organization is a little dated or incomplete. There are no boilerplate tests or spec files, and I want to create tests.

So, as a comparison, when I use Angular CLI to generate a new library, I can see that the root workspace has an angular.json that points to multiple projects in my workspace including my newly created library and other Angular apps.  Each has a test.ts in the projects/[library]/src folder, which is required by karma.conf.js and assumably used by ng when starting up tests.  My swagger generated api doesn't have this file, but I can replicate it manually.  Still, when I run `ng test @mycompany/my-api` I get an error saying `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open /my-workspace/projects/my-api/api/test.js. Notice the generated code and project structures is like ./my-api/**api**/test.js instead of the typical ng generated, ./my-lib/src/test.ts

I can see also that the root workspace has an angular.json, which specifies locations of those test.ts files like so:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "projects/my-company/my-api/src/test.ts",
    "tsConfig": "projects/my-company/my-api/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "projects/my-company/my-api/karma.conf.js"
   }
},
```

If I change ./src/. to ./app/. to match the structure of the swagger generated code, it has no effect.

I could re-organize the generated code manually to match what Angular CLI expects, to make it organized exactly like ng generated code, but then I'd create a maintenance nightmare and not be able to easily update with a regenerated API from swagger.

Any idea how I can tell ng to look for the test.ts in the ./app/. directory instead of the ./src/. directory?  Is it an ng thing or a karma configuration thing.  I can find no tips or information about this anywhere, so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an ng or a karma configuration issue, instead I solved it by revising the tsconfig.spec.json, changing src/test.ts to api/test.ts here:

```
"files": [
  "api/test.ts"
],
```

I've no idea what that angular.json path affects, but I also set that to match the true location as well, but it seemingly has no effect.